# What is the SuppressLint Java annotation?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand the purpose of the `@SuppressLint` Java annotation in the following code:

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new 
  ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading Profile");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
```

What exactly is it used for?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/SuppressLint

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Android Studio uses Lint to check your code for common errors. These are not things that would result in a build error, but violations of best practices or indications of other things that are done incorrectly. The `@SuppressLint` command suppresses these warnings.

In this case, you appear to be using a non-static inner AsyncTask class, which can [leak a context](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html), so there would normally be a warning about it. Putting that command in suppresses the warning. It is generally preferable to fix the warning rather than suppress it unless you know it is not a real issue.

Comment: So how can it be fixed? (Example: To get local formatting use getDateInstance(), getDateTimeInstance(), or getTimeInstance(), or use new SimpleDateFormat(String template, Locale locale) with for example Locale.US for ASCII dates.)